# Subdomain With Custom URL/Domain

Tags: virtualhost, .htaccess, rewrite, domain-name, url

I have a subdomain called 'mysite' at **this.example.org/mysite** which needs to resolve to **mysite.org** in the address bar.

Can this be accomplished with .htaccess in the mysite public_html folder, or will I need to modify virtual host references in the apache httpd.conf?

Comment: Is the same server hosting "this.example.org" and "mysite.org"? And to be clear, you want users to request "this.example.org/mysite/anything" and have the browser address redirect to "mysite.org/anything"? And please clarify which .htaccess you want to update? The one under "this.example.org/mysite/"?

Comment: Yeah, say they type in 'mysite.org'... they would actually be hitting 'this.example.org/mysite', but with the URL in the address bar resolving to 'mysite.org'. i wasn't sure if .htaccess in the subdomain could do this, or if .htaccess in 'this.example.org' would be the proper place.

Comment: ok, I had it backwards then. If you want the user to request 'mysite.org' and have the browser preserve that hostname while serving 'this.example.org/mysite, then you would have to use a reverse proxy config with mod_proxy... either via ProxyPass / ProxyPassReverse directives or if you need more control, then via the [P] flag in a RewriteRule. In either case, sounds like it would go in the .htaccess for the initially requested domain (mysite.org). Check out: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense now... simply having the directives in the .htaccess of that subdomain won't work until apache has the module(s) enabled and configured correctly. I'll use FoamyBeer's approach [below] in the httpd.config, since our sysadmin has given me access to that. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: ok, sorry. I may have misunderstood the goal. I was thinking you were trying to map a domain name (mysite.org) to a hidden URI space (/mysite) under a different domain (this.example.org). If ServerAlias is what you were looking for, then my understanding was way off :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `ServerAlias` directive in site config should work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.bar.int
    ServerAlias www.foo.int
    DocumentRoot /opt/foo
    <Directory /opt/foo>
    Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```